# C++ linked list reverse traversal memory corruption

Tags: c++, memory, corruption

I'm learning C++. As part of a mapping project, I'm trying to (reverse) traverse a linked list from a particular node to the start node via a parent address pointer attribute in the node class. I'm trying to figure out why a parent's address value consistently becomes corrupted, which causes an error and prevents the traversal.

I've extracted the essential components of the project below, along with some helper code that allows the error to be recreated easily.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Node
{
    public:
        int idx;
        Node * addr = nullptr;
        Node * parent_addr = nullptr;
    
        Node (int init_idx, Node * init_parent) {
            idx = init_idx;
            parent_addr = init_parent;
        }
};

void PrintNode(Node & n) {
    cout << "idx: " << n.idx << " addr: " << n.addr << " parent_addr: " << n.parent_addr << endl;
}

void PrintNodeList (vector<Node> & path) {
    for (Node n : path) {PrintNode(n);}
}

void CreateNodeList (const int node_count, vector<Node> & node_list) {
    for (int i=0; i<=(node_count - 1); i++) {
        if (i==0) {
            //  first node parent is null
            node_list.push_back(Node(i, nullptr));
        } else {
            // subsequent nodes parent is previous node
            node_list.push_back(Node(i, &node_list[i-1]));
        }
        // store address of node to clearly follow forward and reverse traversals
        node_list[i].addr = &node_list[i];
    }
    cout << "Node List..." << endl;
    PrintNodeList(node_list);
}

void TraverseNodeList(Node * current_node) {
    cout << endl << "Traversing node list in reverse..." << endl;
    while (current_node != nullptr) {
        PrintNode(*current_node);
        current_node = current_node->parent_addr;
    }
    cout << endl << "Completed reverse traversal." << endl;
}

int main() {
    // generate list of nodes
    const int node_count = 5;
    vector<Node> node_list;
    CreateNodeList (node_count, node_list);
        
    // reverse traverse the list of nodes
    const int last_node = node_count - 1;
    TraverseNodeList(&node_list[last_node]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Here is a sample node list (node index, address of the node, address of node's parent):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRDC8.png)

[Here is a traversal corrupting at the start node:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o46Wk.png)

[Here is a traversal corrupting before the start node:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezhBG.png)

**Actual CreateNodeList function:**

This code is extracted from an A* search project. As the map is traversed, the neighbors of the node being examined (current_node) are updated (the parent attribute is set and they are marked as visited) and pushed onto the `std::vector<node *>` node_list via the following:

```
for (auto neighbor : current_node->neighbors) {
    neighbor->parent = current_node; 
    node_list.push_back(neighbor); 
    neighbor->visited = true;
}
```

Comment: How do you know that it is `parent_addr` that gets corrupted, rather than, say `addr`? The lack of a copy constructor is problematic if you want to keep `this->addr` equal to `this`. (Why do you even store `addr` instead of taking the address of the object?)

Comment: Would it make a difference of you called `node_list.reserve(5)` some time between defining `node_list` and the first call to `node_list.push_back`?

Comment: Reexamine the documentation for [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), then carefully examine `CreateNodeList` to see if you can see the problem.

Comment: Vorian, SamV actually gives the right answer so I've deleted mine. Suggest you accept the former.

Answer (score 2):

```
node_list.push_back(Node(i, &node_list[i-1]));
```

A pointer to the previous element in the vector gets passed to a constructor of a new `Node`'s element.

This immediately becomes undefined behavior. It is a fundamental property of `std::vector`s that when `std::vector` reallocates this invalidates all existing pointers and iterators to the vector.

After constructing this new `Node`, it gets passed as a parameter to `push_back`, which may result in reallocation of the vector's contents, thus invalidating this and all previous pointers to the vector.

If it is necessary to juggle pointers to elements in a vector, additional work must be done to ensure that the vector will never reallocate. This is outside the scope of this question, and would be rather cumbersome so probably the best thing to do here is to rethink the overall design of your linked list so that it does not use `std::vector`s, perhaps `std::list` will be an alternative (however since `std::list` is, itself, a linked list, that would be somewhat dubious). In any case, the reason for the crash is undefined behavior due to referencing pointers to values in a vector that gets reallocated, invalidating all pointers to the values in the vector.

Comment: Good call, Sam, addresses of other elements of a vector *within* the vector is definitely a bad idea. Reallocation could be fatal in that case. As an aside, storing indexes (rather than pointers) into the vector would fix this issue since the indexes are turned into addresses when used, not when created.

Comment: Sam, thanks for your response. I understand (now) that the `std::vector` is not ideal in this example because of the reallocation problem. However, `std::vector` and the structure of the node class (except for ->addr, which I added for debugging) are components of the coursework. I added more explanation of the actual problem to the question.

Comment: It's unclear to me how the new information that has any relevance to the fact that `std::vector` works the way it works. The new code references some class with`neighbors`, `parent`, and `visited` as its members. None of them are members of `Node`, as shown in the original question. If the goal here is to create a vector, which will remain unchanged afterwards, then simply use `reserve()` to reserve the vector's size, and then `push_back`ing the same number of values guarantees that the vector will not reallocate. See your C++ textbook for more information.